# Unable to load data from local json file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
         $select = $('#people');
         //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
         $.ajax({
             type:'GET',
             url: 'simple.json',
             dataType:'JSON',
             success:function(data){
                 //clear the current content of the select
                 $select.html('');
                 //iterate over the data and append a select option
                 $.each(data.person, function(key, val){
                     $select.append('<option >' + val.firstName+ '</option>');
                 })
             },
             error:function(){
                 //if there is an error append a 'none available' option
                 $select.html('<option >none available</option>');
             }
         });
         </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <select id="people"></select>
  </body>

</html>
```

The data from local json file cannot be read using jQuery ajax.

Even I am trying the same code using `$.getjson()`. The output is not being returned.

This is my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ys2xxOn1oUCeNL3wqcvJ?p=preview

Comment: what does `simple.json` return?

Comment: Hi @guradio it is a data file.see my plunker.

Comment: i updated the plunker you should use `employees` not `person`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `data.person` to `data.employees`, wrap the code in a document ready statement

https://plnkr.co/edit/PemDjZFAsFCcH16NfdQu?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Change data.person to data.employees and move script to bottom body page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <select id="people"></select>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
         $select = $('#people');
         //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
         $.ajax({
             type:'GET',
             url: 'simple.json',
             dataType:'JSON',
             success:function(data){
                 //clear the current content of the select
                 $select.html('');
                 //iterate over the data and append a select option
                 $.each(data.employees, function(key, val){
                    $select.append('<option >' + val.firstName+ '</option>');
                 });
                 $select.html(options);
             },
             error:function(){
                 //if there is an error append a 'none available' option
                 $select.html('<option >none available</option>');
             }
         });
         </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fixed version: https://plnkr.co/edit/p4C7Lxf5EzyBSSEFQZ6D?p=preview.

Code pasted below. I made two important changes (and a couple cosmetic ones):

1. I changed `data.person` to `data.employees` to match the data.
2. I moved the script down below where the `<select>` tag is introduced. In your code, `$select` tries to find that element before it actually exists.

   ```
   <script>
        $select = $('#people');
        //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: 'simple.json',
            dataType:'JSON',
            success:function(data){
                //clear the current content of the select
                $select.empty();
                //iterate over the data and append a select option
                $.each(data.employees, function(key, val){
                    $select.append($('<option>' + val.firstName+ '</option>'));
                })
            },
            error:function(){
                //if there is an error append a 'none available' option
                $select.html('<option>none available</option>');
            }
        });
    </script>
   ```